# SearchView Filter, get correct position in listview

Tags: android, listview, searchview

How to get the correct item when the filtered result display in the ListView and when the filtered result is selected it will display the correct output in another fragment, so far this is my current codes.

Current Problem Output:
[image: Problem]

My codes so far:

```
YourGroup.java

package com.findforme.www.myapplication;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class YourGroup extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,SearchView.OnCloseListener{

    private String TAG = YourGroup.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView gridView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    ListAdapterShowGroups adapter;

    ArrayList<your_groups> your_groupList;

    public static YourGroup newInstance() {
        YourGroup fragment = new YourGroup();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void findViews(View view) {

        your_groupList = new ArrayList<>();
        mSearchView = view.findViewById(R.id.floating_search_view);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.lv_showGroup);
        gridView.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
        new GetGroups().execute();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        final FilterHelper filterHelper = new FilterHelper(your_groupList,adapter,getActivity());
        adapter = new ListAdapterShowGroups(filterHelper.currentList,getActivity());
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
        return false;
    }

    public static class FilterHelper extends Filter{
        ArrayList<your_groups> currentList;
        ListAdapterShowGroups adapter;
        Context c;

        FilterHelper(ArrayList<your_groups> currentList, ListAdapterShowGroups adapter, Context c){
            this.currentList = currentList;
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                ArrayList<your_groups> foundFilters = new ArrayList<>();

                your_groups your_group = null;

                for (int i=0;i<currentList.size();i++){
                    your_group = currentList.get(i);

                    if(your_group.GroupName.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)){
                        foundFilters.add(your_group);
                    }
                }

                filterResults.count=foundFilters.size();
                filterResults.values=foundFilters;

            } else {
                filterResults.count =currentList.size();
                filterResults.values=currentList;
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

            if(filterResults.count == 0){
                adapter.invalidate();
            } else {
                adapter.setYourGroups((ArrayList<your_groups>)filterResults.values);
                adapter.refresh();
            }
        }
    }


    private class GetGroups extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Retrieving data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            int id = MainActivity.user.getId();
            String user_id = Integer.toString(id);

            //String url = "https://findforme2018.000webhostapp.com/show_groups_joined.php?id="+user_id;
            String url = "http://192.168.211.1/Capstone%202018/FindForMe/show_groups_joined.php?id="+user_id;
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if( jsonStr != null){
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONArray groups = jsonObj.getJSONArray("group_join");

                    your_groups your_groups;

                    your_groupList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < groups.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);

                        your_groups = new your_groups();

                        your_groups.setGroupName(c.getString("group_name"));
                        your_groups.setId(c.getInt("group_id"));

                        your_groupList.add(your_groups);

                    }
                }catch (final JSONException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "No groups join yet",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            adapter = new ListAdapterShowGroups(your_groupList,getActivity());
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        int id = your_groupList.get(i).id;
                        String group_id = Integer.toString(id);
                        String groupname = your_groupList.get(i).GroupName;

                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("group_id", group_id);
                        args.putString("groupname", groupname);

                        SelectedGroup fragment = new SelectedGroup();
                        fragment.setArguments(args);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                groupname,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.content_main
                                        , fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();




                    }
                });
        }
    }

    View myView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your_group, container, false);
        findViews(myView);
        return myView;


    }
}
```

This is the adapter that display the data in listview and its filter

```
package com.findforme.www.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListAdapterShowGroups extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<your_groups> valueList;
    private YourGroup.FilterHelper filterHelper;

    ListAdapterShowGroups(ArrayList<your_groups> listValue, Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.valueList = listValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.valueList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return this.valueList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ListAdapterShowGroups.ViewItem viewItem;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            viewItem = new ListAdapterShowGroups.ViewItem();

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgroup_layout,null);

            viewItem.image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupImage);
            viewItem.groupname = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_groupName);

            convertView.setTag(viewItem);
        }
        else
        {
            viewItem = (ListAdapterShowGroups.ViewItem)convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewItem.groupname.setText(valueList.get(position).getGroupName());
        String img = valueList.get(position).getGroupName();

        //Glide.with(this.context).load("https://findforme2018.000webhostapp.com/Group_Image/"+img+".jpg").asBitmap().into(viewItem.image);

        Glide.with(this.context).load("http://192.168.211.1/Capstone%202018/FindForMe/Group_Image/"+img+".jpg").asBitmap().into(viewItem.image);


        return convertView;
    }

    public void setYourGroups(ArrayList<your_groups> filteredYourGroups){
        this.valueList = filteredYourGroups;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(filterHelper == null){
            filterHelper = new YourGroup.FilterHelper(valueList,this,context);
        }

        return filterHelper;
    }

    public void refresh(){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void invalidate(){
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

    class ViewItem {
        Integer id;
        TextView groupname;
        ImageView image;
    }
}

your_groups.java
package com.findforme.www.myapplication;

public class your_groups {
    public String GroupName;
    public Integer id;

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGroupName(){
        return GroupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String GroupName){
        this.GroupName = GroupName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
         text_view.setText(adapter.getItem(position - 1) + "");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code and change according your code..

```
public class IndexItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IndexItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> implements Filterable {
private List<UserData> userVoList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<UserData> filterUserVoList = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private String userId;
onItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(IndexItemAdapter.onItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

public IndexItemAdapter(Context context, List<UserData> userVoList, String userId) {
    this.userVoList = userVoList;
    this.context = context;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.filterUserVoList = userVoList;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();

            if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                filterUserVoList = userVoList;
            } else {

                ArrayList<UserData> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (UserData userData : userVoList) {

                    if (userData.getSubject().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || userData.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || userData.getMessages().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                        filteredList.add(userData);
                    }
                }

                filterUserVoList = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filterUserVoList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filterUserVoList = (ArrayList<UserData>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public interface onItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(UserData userData);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.index_row_layout, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final UserData userData = filterUserVoList.get(position);
    holder.tvName.setText(CommonUtils.checkForNullValue(userData.getSubject()));
    holder.tvContent.setText(CommonUtils.checkForNullValue(userData.getMessages()));
    if (userData.getUserVo() != null) {
        holder.tvEmail.setText(userData.getUserVo().getEmail());
        Glide.with(context).load(CommonUtils.checkForNullValue(userData.getUserVo().getPhoto())).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.big_user))
                .into(holder.ivUserImage);
        if (userId.equals(userData.getReceiverId())) {
            holder.ivRecivedIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.forward);
        } else {
            holder.ivRecivedIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.reply);
        }
    }
}

private void changeTextColor(TextView textView, int color) {
    textView.setTextColor(color);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filterUserVoList.size();
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.irlIvUserImage)
    ImageView ivUserImage;
    @BindView(R.id.irlTvName)
    TextView tvName;
    @BindView(R.id.irlTvEmail)
    TextView tvEmail;
    @BindView(R.id.irlTvDes)
    TextView tvContent;
    @BindView(R.id.irlTvTime)
    TextView tvTime;
    @BindView(R.id.irlIvGetImage)
    ImageView ivRecivedIcon;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
}
```

and search view in.. make sure your adapter not null

```
  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            indexItemAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toLowerCase());
            indexItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: still the same result sir